# How to select the distinct rows from a table having a specific condition?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains data in this format.

```
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
| id  | grade_id | student_id | subject_id |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
| 249 |        1 |         27 |          1 |
| 250 |        1 |         27 |          2 |
| 251 |        1 |         27 |          4 |
| 252 |        1 |         28 |          1 |
| 253 |        1 |         28 |          2 |
| 254 |        1 |         28 |          4 |
| 255 |        1 |         29 |          1 |
| 256 |        2 |         29 |          2 |
| 257 |        3 |         29 |          4 |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
```

I need all the student_id s having grade_id = 1 for all subject_id, which query i will use to get the student_id.

I need the result of the query should be like this?

student_id

```
  27  
  28
```

Comment: Show us your sql query.

Comment: To use the ORM you need models. You can create models for already existing tables too.

Comment: Please don't completely change requirement of question this frequently. You earlier needed answer for Django also, which you later removed. :/

Comment: Ok, but exactly I need the students having A grade in all subjects, I don't know how to write query for it.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL:

`SELECT student_id FROM table WHERE student_id NOT IN (SELECT students_id FROM table WHERE grade_id != 1)`

In Django:

```
from django.db.models import Q
not_eligible = Model.objects.all().filter(~Q(grade_id = 1))
               .values('student_id').distinct()
eligible = Model.objects.all().filter(~Q(student_id_in = not_eligible))
           .values('student_id').distinct())
# eligible -> all student_id
```